# Copy value inside column based on another column (ID) in Excel or Jamovi

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I can't figure out how to make it work. Some people asked similar questions in r-forums but it seems my understanding is to basic to make the transfer.
I have a large repeated measures dataset in long format and i performed a cluster-analysis. Now I need to copy the value signalling group-membership inside the second column based on Participant-ID.
The table underneath shows how it looks at the moment. I need to automatically fill in the blank spaces for cluster_membership with the same values depending on the id.

| ID | Cluster_membership |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 |  |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 |  |
| 3 | 5 |
| 3 |  |

| ID | Cluster_membership that i need |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 3 | 5 |

Thank you in advance,
Philipp

Comment: You need this in R or in Excel? Because you have used both tags and its confusing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is as you show it, with only a single `Cluster_membership` per `ID`, you can obtain your desired output using `Power Query`, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365 Excel

- Select some cell in your original table
- `Data => Get&Transform => From Table/Range`
- When the PQ UI opens, navigate to `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table Name in Line 2 of the code.
- Replace the existing code with the **M-Code** below
- Change the table name in line 2 of the pasted code to your "real" table name
- Examine any comments, and also the `Applied Steps` window, to better understand the algorithm and steps

***M Code***

```
let

//change table name in next line to actual name in your workbook
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table11"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Cluster_membership", Int64.Type}}),

//Group by ID and extract Cluster_membership
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ID"}, {
        {"all", each _, type table [ID=nullable number, Cluster_membership=nullable number]},
        {"Cluster_membership", each List.Max([Cluster_membership])}
        }),

//remove unneeded columns and expand the resultant table (except for the Cluster_membership column
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"ID"}),
    #"Expanded all" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "all", {"ID"}, {"ID"})
in
    #"Expanded all"
```

[image]

***Note:***
*Another way of getting the same output would be to*

- Sort the table by ID and then cluster
- Fill-Up the cluster column

*I'm not sure which will be faster on your data set.  The code with sorting is simpler, but sorting sometimes takes a while in PQ.  You can try both methods. If you do, please let me know the results of comparison*

***M Code (sort method)***

```
let

//change table name in next line to actual name in your workbook
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table11"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Cluster_membership", Int64.Type}}),

//sort by ID and cluster, then fill-up
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type",{{"ID", Order.Ascending}, {"Cluster_membership", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Filled Up" = Table.FillUp(#"Sorted Rows",{"Cluster_membership"})
in
    #"Filled Up"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help @Ron Rosenfeld. The first one already worked perfectly i didn't even get to the sorting method.